# XML splitting query very slow

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, xpath

I have a query to split a delimited string into to multiple columns. The query is extremely slow and takes more than 5 minutes to handle 80444 rows. How can I improve execution time?

```
  WITH cte (Execution_ID,Intake_Generic_ID, [File_Name],F1,Report_Attributes) AS ( SELECT 
    Execution_ID,  Intake_Generic_ID,
    [File_Name],  F1,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Report><Attribute>' 
        + REPLACE(F1,'~', '</Attribute><Attribute>') 
        + '</Attribute></Report>') AS Report_Attributes FROM [dbo].[Intake_Generic] )

SELECT 
    Execution_ID,  Intake_Generic_ID,
    [File_Name],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionDate],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[2]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionNum],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[3]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Interchange],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[4]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Gantry],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[6]','varchar(50)'))) AS [GantryDirection],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[7]','varchar(50)'))) AS [GantryEntryExit],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[8]','varchar(50)'))) AS [RTCID],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[9]','varchar(100)'))) AS [Vehicle_Classification_Cd],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[10]','varchar(100)'))) AS [VehicleClassification],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[11]','varchar(100)'))) AS [Txn_Iden_Cd],  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[12]','varchar(100)'))) AS [TransactionIdentification] FROM  cte S 
        CROSS APPLY Report_Attributes.nodes('/Report') AS Tbl(Report)  order by Intake_Generic_ID
```

Comment: Why is `Intake_Generic.F1` stored in that horrible format to begin with? And why do you need to use XML at all?

Comment: @200_success Intake_Generic.F1 is a ~ delimited string which I get from the source file.

Comment: But why is it loaded into the database as one long string rather than as a table?

Comment: @200_success - I have no control on how it is been loaded. I have visibility to only the intake table with the long string.

Comment: @need_the_buzz please do not change the code in your question after answers have been posted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't do much for the performance, but maintaining this kind of T-SQL is painful, so proper formatting is essential.

The `FROM` clause is hidden, and one has to pay very close attention to notice the `ORDER BY` clause as well. Consider:

```
WITH cte (Execution_ID,Intake_Generic_ID, [File_Name],F1,Report_Attributes) AS ( 
    SELECT 
         Execution_ID
        ,Intake_Generic_ID
        ,[File_Name]
        ,F1
        ,CONVERT(XML,
            '<Report><Attribute>' + 
            REPLACE(F1,'~', '</Attribute <Attribute>') + 
            '</Attribute></Report>') AS Report_Attributes 
    FROM [dbo].[Intake_Generic]
)
SELECT 
     Execution_ID
    ,Intake_Generic_ID
    ,[File_Name]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionDate]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[2]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionNum]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[3]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Interchange]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[4]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Gantry]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[6]','varchar(50)'))) AS [GantryDirection]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[7]','varchar(50)'))) AS [GantryEntryExit]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[8]','varchar(50)'))) AS [RTCID]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[9]','varchar(100)'))) AS [Vehicle_Classification_Cd]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[10]','varchar(100)'))) AS [VehicleClassification]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[11]','varchar(100)'))) AS [Txn_Iden_Cd]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[12]','varchar(100)'))) AS [TransactionIdentification] 
FROM  cte S 
    CROSS APPLY Report_Attributes.nodes('/Report') AS Tbl(Report)
ORDER BY Intake_Generic_ID
```

XQuery *is* slower than "normal" T-SQL querying, pretty much by definition.

If the results don't *need* to be sorted, or if they can be sorted by whoever is consuming this data, then removing the `ORDER BY` clause should give you a little boost, but I suspect the `CROSS APPLY` is much more expensive than the sorting.

---

Looking more closely at what the query is doing, I'd say the XQuery isn't *required* for this to work - it was clever, but as you saw, a total performance killer.

> ```
>     ,F1
>     ,CONVERT(XML,
>         '<Report><Attribute>' + 
>         REPLACE(F1,'~', '</Attribute <Attribute>') + 
>         '</Attribute></Report>') AS Report_Attributes
> ```

You're building the XML from the contents of `F1`, by replacing occurrences of `~` within the `varchar` value.

If the data is shaped anything like a list of <s>comma</s> tilde-separated values, you could write a table-valued function that returns a table with 12 records given that `F1` string:

```
declare @result as table (
     AttributeIndex int
    ,AttributeValue varchar(50)
);
```

Your CTE could be `CROSS APPLY`-ing that function with the contents of `Intake_Generic`, and the actual `SELECT` wouldn't have much work left to do. And without XML involved, I'm willing to bet that you'd get the results much, much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took out the order by and the CTE from the query. The query is done in like 14 seconds now. I agree to your comment to use the table valued function for better performance, but we are prohibited from creating functions in production.

Comment: @need_the_buzz interesting.. could you be missing an index?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, splitting a character delimited string via this "xml trick", is the fastest approach AFAIC. The TV-UDF you are speaking of, would have to do the splitting in the one or other way too. CHARINDEX and its friends won't perform better...

Comment: @Mat'sMug About your question above "could you be missing and index?" The CTE is handled very similar to a declared table variable. The optimizer won't be able to use the indexes for sorting outside of the CTE. This is one (maybe the biggest) weakness of CTEs. They should - if ever possible - be used to handle rather small row counts, to prepare variables and do pre-calculations.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, "need_the_buzz" posted some code which brought me to some more comparisons. It might be of interest for you too. If you let all 4 solutions work in one go, the percentage of the batches is 1, 1, 8 and 90... at least with the very small amount of test-data...

Comment: @Shnugo this method is *extremely* prone to poor performance due to repeated reevaluation of the expression and should be avoided. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32082514/73226. CLR is the fastest way.

Comment: @MartinSmith, as far as I see the problem discussed in your link is **not** related to the string splitting approach via XML itself, but rather  related to the usage within `VALUES`. CLR should be the fastest, but still I think, that this splitting method is the best if you stick to "pure" T-SQL. It is obvious, that one must put this in a way, where the conversion is not done over and over again...

Comment: @Shnugo - The point is that you have no control over whether it is evaluated once and cached or evaluated many times. The use of `VALUES` there is irrelevant. Here's an example of the same issue in a query without `VALUES` http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30862/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith, OK, I see what you mean... Well, up to now I never stumbled into this problem... First of all I use a CTE at the beginning to do the REPLACE and second I use CAST instead of CONVERT to get the XML. At the moment I haven't enough time, but I'll set up some tests later...

Answer (score 3):

According to comments below this is a new, shorter code without sorting, to make it comparable:

First I create test data

```
CREATE TABLE Intake_Generic(Execution_ID INT,Intake_Generic_ID INT,[File_Name] VARCHAR(100),F1 VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERt INTO Intake_Generic VALUES
 (1,2,'SomeFileName','This~is~a~test')
,(2,1,'SomeFileName','And~just~another~test');
GO
```

Now "my" code with a CTE

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Execution_ID,
        Intake_Generic_ID,
        [File_Name],
        CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(F1)),'~', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Report_Attributes
    FROM [dbo].[Intake_Generic]
)

SELECT 
    Execution_ID,
    Intake_Generic_ID,
    [File_Name],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report_Attributes.value('x[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib1],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report_Attributes.value('x[2]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib2],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report_Attributes.value('x[3]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib3],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Report_Attributes.value('x[4]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib4]
FROM  cte
GO
```

The CTE will be inlined and therefore produce exactly the same execution plan as "your" approach with the XML-cast in the FROM clause (not exactly as you copied it into the comment, because this wouldn't produce the same result, see below):

```
SELECT Execution_ID,
       Intake_Generic_ID,
       [File_Name],
       LTRIM(RTRIM(NewXML.value('x[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib1],
       LTRIM(RTRIM(NewXML.value('x[2]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib2],
       LTRIM(RTRIM(NewXML.value('x[3]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib3],
       LTRIM(RTRIM(NewXML.value('x[4]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Attrib4]
FROM (  SELECT NewXML=CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(F1,'~','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) 
              ,Execution_ID
              ,Intake_Generic_ID
              ,[File_Name] 
        FROM Intake_Generic ) AS CastXML 
GO
```

This is the code as you posted it into your comment. It is - according to the execution plan - about 8 times slower and comes back with only the first value:

```
SELECT Execution_ID
     , Intake_Generic_ID
     , [File_Name]
     , LTRIM(RTRIM( x.i.value('i[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionDate] 
FROM (  SELECT NewXML=CAST('<Report><i>'+REPLACE(F1,'~','</i><i>')+'</i></Report>' AS XML) 
              ,Execution_ID
              ,Intake_Generic_ID
              ,[File_Name] 
        FROM Intake_Generic ) AS CastXML 
CROSS APPLY NewXML.nodes('/Report') x(i);
GO
```

And finally these is the code as it comes from the other answer (reduced to produce the same result for comparability):

It takes more than 90% of the batch...

```
WITH cte (Execution_ID,Intake_Generic_ID, [File_Name],Report_Attributes) AS ( 
    SELECT 
         Execution_ID
        ,Intake_Generic_ID
        ,[File_Name]
        ,CONVERT(XML,
            '<Report><Attribute>' + 
            REPLACE(F1,'~', '</Attribute><Attribute>') + 
            '</Attribute></Report>') AS Report_Attributes 
    FROM [dbo].[Intake_Generic]
)
SELECT 
     Execution_ID
    ,Intake_Generic_ID
    ,[File_Name]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionDate]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[2]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionNum]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[3]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Interchange]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(Report.value('Attribute[4]','varchar(50)'))) AS [Gantry]
FROM  cte S 
    CROSS APPLY Report_Attributes.nodes('/Report') AS Tbl(Report)
GO
```

So: Please check these approaches. I'm afraid your code might be quick but only because it doesn't produce what you expect... (or I got wrong what you need)

Comment: please explain your answer more so the OP and future readers can understand it.

Comment: @chillworld added some explanation. Hope this is clear now..

Comment: I voted the answer, but can you do it next time outside the coding part?  Btw, welcome here.

Comment: @Shnugo - I have tried your query. It took 43 seconds to run against my dataset but the query I have right now as per Mat's comments took me only 14 seconds.

Comment: Code which I have right now.


`SELECT
    Execution_ID,
 Intake_Generic_ID,
    [File_Name],
    LTRIM(RTRIM( x.i.value('i[1]','varchar(50)'))) AS [TransactionDate]
FROM
( SELECT NewXML=CAST('<Report><i>'+REPLACE(F1,'~','</i><i>')+'</i></Report>' AS XML)
    ,Execution_ID,Intake_Generic_ID,[File_Name]
 FROM Intake_Generic 
) CastXML
CROSS APPLY NewXML.nodes('/Report') x(i)`

Comment: @need_the_buzz The only reason for this can be the sorting. Please try to take away the "SortInx" everywhere and test it again. Is there an index in the column you want to sort after?

Comment: @need_the_buzz, I think, that your code (as posted within the comment above) does not produce what you need. Please check my edited answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the XML method of string splitting where it can perform horribly because of repeated re-evaluations of the `REPLACE` and the `CAST` to `XML`. [More details in this blog post.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/05/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.aspx)

The best performing method is CLR but it sounds as though this will not be an option for you. As the maximum split index of interest is known in advance a more robust method, avoiding XML, might be

```
SELECT  Execution_ID,
        Intake_Generic_ID,
        File_Name,
        F1, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C0,  C1- C0 - 1))) AS TransactionDate, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C1,  C2- C1 - 1))) AS TransactionNum, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C2,  C3- C2 - 1))) AS Interchange, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C3,  C4- C3 - 1))) AS Gantry, 
--      LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C4,  C5- C4 - 1))) AS Unknown, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C5,  C6- C5 - 1))) AS GantryDirection, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C6,  C7- C6 - 1))) AS GantryEntryExit, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C7,  C8- C7 - 1))) AS RTCID, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C8,  C9- C8 - 1))) AS Vehicle_Classification_Cd, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F, C9, C10- C9 - 1))) AS VehicleClassification, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F,C10, C11-C10 - 1))) AS Txn_Iden_Cd, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(F,C11, C12-C11 - 1))) AS TransactionIdentification
FROM [dbo].[Intake_Generic] 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1, F1 + REPLICATE('~',12))) V0(C0,F)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C0 ))) V1 (C1)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C1 ))) V2 (C2)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C2 ))) V3 (C3)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C3 ))) V4 (C4)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C4 ))) V5 (C5)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C5 ))) V6 (C6)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C6 ))) V7 (C7)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C7 ))) V8 (C8)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C8 ))) V9 (C9)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C9) )) V10(C10)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C10))) V11(C11)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1 + CHARINDEX('~',F, C11))) V12(C12)
```

---

Or another way would be to use Jeff Moden's approach [from this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) with the necessary adjustments to work without creating a function and to `PIVOT` the results into a single row.

```
WITH E1(N)
     AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1), --10E+1 or 10 rows
     E2(N)
     AS (SELECT 1 FROM   E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
     E4(N)
     AS (SELECT 1 FROM   E2 a, E2 b) --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    SELECT  Execution_ID,
            Intake_Generic_ID,
            File_Name,
            F1, 
            [1]  AS TransactionDate, 
            [2]  AS TransactionNum, 
            [3]  AS Interchange, 
            [4]  AS Gantry, 
    --      [5]  AS Unknown, 
            [6]  AS GantryDirection, 
            [7]  AS GantryEntryExit, 
            [8]  AS RTCID, 
            [9]  AS Vehicle_Classification_Cd, 
            [10] AS VehicleClassification, 
            [11] AS Txn_Iden_Cd, 
            [12] AS TransactionIdentification
FROM  dbo.Intake_Generic ig
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   (SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
                                   Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ig.F1, l.N1, l.L1)))
                            FROM   (SELECT N1 = s.N1,
                                           L1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('~', ig.F1, s.N1), 0) - s.N1, 8000)
                                    FROM   (SELECT N1 = 1
                                            UNION ALL
                                            SELECT N1 = Nums.N + 1
                                            FROM   (SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(ig.F1), 0)) 
                                                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                                                    FROM   E4) Nums(N)
                                            WHERE  SUBSTRING(ig.F1, Nums.N, 1) = '~') s) l) 
                          f
                          PIVOT (MAX(Item) 
                            FOR ItemNumber IN ([1],  [2],  [3], 
                                               [4],  [5],  [6], 
                                               [7],  [8],  [9], 
                                               [10], [11], [12])) P
                   ) CA;
```